# Oracle Reports-How To Add Field Object To Repeating Frame

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I want to add field object to an existing repeating frame.But when I drag the field, new frame is generated.

See Image below.

[image]

I want to do is put the field **F_PO_NUMBER** under **R_INVOICE** frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to

- create a backup copy of that RDF file - you might need to restore the report if something goes wrong
- go to paper layout editor
- turn flex OFF (so that frames wouldn't stretch)
- select any field in the R_INVOICE frame (for example, F_INVOICE_NUMBER)
- copy/paste it (Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V)
- a new item (named F_INVOICE_NUMBER1) will be created slightly right & below from the original item)
- move it to a new position

  - if necessary, switch flex ON (and, possibly, confine ON/OFF), but **be very careful** because you might spoil current layout, and - if you do that - it might be difficult to revert changes. Undo works only 1 level back
- change its name & source so that they are appropriate (i.e. F_PO_NUMBER)
- save & run the report. Hopefully, it'll be OK.

P.S. As you already have the R_1 frame (which is useless), I'd suggest you to remove (in paper layout editor) it, as well as current F_PO_NUMBER field (visible on your screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

- *Doble-click* on the `Paper Layout` node.
- Touch `R_INVOICE` repeating frame on the `Object Navigator`.
- Change *Fill colour* of `R_INVOICE` by selecting a different than that already has ( *colour palette* pointers are located on the left side of the `Paper Layout` ).
- Let's choose `gray` as fill colour, and then there will appear a great gray box on the `Paper Layout`.
- Just drag `F_PO_NUMBER` to the inside of that `gray` box. If some frames or objects slides as you drag `F_PO_NUMBER`, apply immediately an *undo* by pressing `Ctrl+Z`, and play with `Flex On/Off` or `Confine On/Off` buttons up to your object is able to be removed into that `gray` box.

Comment: Thanks again. But the problem is that I can't align the object properly.So it still creating new frame.

Comment: @ktaro hi, welcome. On the top menu there's `Layout`->`Alignment` .. perhaps it helps.

Comment: teşekkür ederim @phileoseda .

Comment: Rica ederim. :)